# Why photoshop distort imported image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, visual-artifacts, import

I've made a screenshot of my phone screen and imported it in Photoshop by dragging from disk. However it's clean "as-is" image of the phone screen, it has appeared in photoshop slightly blurred. How can I avoid this behavior? On the picture there are zoom of regular Preview mac os app on the left and Photoshop version on the right.

[image]

Comment: Did you make any changes to the image in Photoshop or did you only open the image directly into Photoshop?

Comment: Just drag it, no changes..

Comment: The image on the right is lower resolution than the one on the left (only slightly but it is). Did you place the image in an already open document or did you simply open the image in Photoshop?

Comment: I've dragged it to already opened document (iPhone 6 render with blank screen)

Comment: What kind of device did you take the screenshot from?

Comment: This is iPhone 6s screenshot (750 × 1334)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the resolution on the destination file (PSD workspace in this case) matches the resolution on the original/source file. You can check the resolution by going to Image >> Image Size in the Photoshop Menu.

Comment: Yes, it happened because the height of canvas was less than the height of dragged image...

Comment: @MaratAl Whenever I want to place images, I usually open them on their own, as a separate document, and then drag from that open document to my desired one.  This way, you can ensure that the image you are working with gets inserted at its full size.

Answer (score -3):

Actually your image in already blurred. If you save this photoshop file as a Jpeg. You'll find same result.

Don't worry about it. 
But if you want totally pixel free file then you have to remake the whole design.

And if you are confused about the blurred boxes then let me tell you that witj the help of these boxes you can do better editing in your image.

Comment: No, it's not blurred, you can see this on the left part.